# navigation controller doesn't work on all views

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I'm working on a project and I have a tabbar controller and there are four views connected to the tabbar controller , however all views are working just fine but one , the view does not recognize that it is embedded from a navigation controller which results (no back button and no tabbar)
here is a picture of the part that is not working in the storyboard :

[image]

Comment: you need to add back button yourself. because nice one viewcontroller is root of navigationview controller

Comment: I need to show the tab bar , the back button is not a big deal @SourLeangChhean

Comment: I think when you run it will show (Nice one Viewcontroller)

Comment: My problem is not with niceone viewcontroller , it is with the views that are connected with niceone viewcontroller @SourLeangChhean

Comment: Please make sure you push viewcontroller not present viewcontroller that connected with it.

Comment: I use show(e.g push) @SourLeangChhean

Comment: You can  try use push maybe it work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved !
The segue was of type show(e.g push) however unlike the other views this one didn't work with navigation controller , so what I've done is that I deleted the segue and created another one with exactly the same attributes , and it worked !
Thank you guys for your efforts